# Is it possible to check for blips in internet using SSH tunnels?

Tags: macos, networking, bash, ssh, tunnel

So basically at work we're losing internet connectivity for just a few seconds at a time, which is enough to kill our SSH tunnels, kill our VoIP calls, etc. I have a cronjob set up with [my own script](https://github.com/NobleUplift/NetCheck) to detect major outages (lasting longer than one minute), but I cannot detect these seconds-long outages.

Usually during the day I have an SSH tunnel connected to one of our servers. This connection lasts for most of the day, so I'm thinking of creating a script that creates another connection to the same server, logs when the connection to the server is broken, and then re-establishes the connection for further logging. Is this possible with basic bash?

Comment: It is very unusual that a very short interruption would cause an SSH session to break.  I have had SSH session that survive after a reboot of an intermediate router between the client and server.  Are you sure you have properly diagnosed your problem?  What you probably should do is setup a real monitoring system.  Something like Smokeping, Nagios, etc instead of trying to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Well previously we were losing internet for 5-15 minutes at a time. Actually, last Friday the largest downtime was 23 minutes. However, the week before that we weren't getting long outages. I've been getting "Broken pipe", another co-worker would lose connection to Skype or be unable to send emails, and webpages will just fail to load for a few seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to counteract loss of connectivity for ssh sessions.

First, you may wish to set the options ServerAliveInterval, ClientAliveInterval and ClientAliveCountMax. ServerAliveInterval is the number of seconds that the client will wait before sending a null packet to the server (to keep the connection alive), a value of 60 is typical. ClientAliveInterval is the number of seconds that the server will wait before sending a null packet to the client. Lastly, ClientAliveCountMax is the number of ClientAliveInterval's that the client is allowed to remain silnet before the connection is broken; default is 3, meaning three times the ClientAliveInterval time lapse.

Alternatively, you may use [Mosh](https://mosh.mit.edu/), the mobile shell, which...

> allows roaming, supports intermittent connectivity, and provides intelligent local echo and line editing of user keystrokes. Mosh is a replacement for SSH. It's more robust and responsive, especially over Wi-Fi, cellular, and long-distance links.Mosh is free software, available for GNU/Linux, FreeBSD, Solaris, Mac OS X, and Android.

And then, you can use [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/)  instead of ssh:

> autossh - Automatically restart SSH sessions and tunnels

Which way you go depens mostly on tastes. As for me, I use *autossh* for tunnels I wish to have permanently up, especially reverse tunnels; I use *mosh* for truly disastrous connections, like when ssh'ing into my lab from a plane or a car. For all other cases, a judicious choice
of the above parameters for openssh will do: for instance, my .ssh/config file contains the following lines:

```
 Host * 
    ServerAliveInterval 60
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

and likewise for the servers, in the file */etc/sshd_config*.

And, by the way, to monitor your connection over longish stretches of time, you may use [mtr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTR_%28software%29) (= My TraceRoute), a smart combination of traceroute and ping which will do a traceroute every so many seconds (default = 1 second) to a given site, and will smoothly update the statistics of successful pings, giving you an opportunity to establish at least the average fraction of uptime, but not their distribution.

Comment: About time I answered this. The solution was to switch ISPs from Comcast to AT&T, but these are great suggestions when I'm working on the go.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I made some tweaking to my script so that it essentially runs continuously and starts logging when it loses connection, instead of looking for a lost connection:

https://github.com/NobleUplift/NetCheck

But really, we just needed to switch ISPs.